# Jenkins pipeline syntax - if something is installed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkins pipeline I need a step to be executed only when `chromedriver --version` can actually print something. What's a good way to do it?

Pseudo code :

```
node('slave-1') {
  stage('configure slave1') {
    if ('chromedriver --version' !== null) sh "${script}"      
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node() {

  stage('configure slave1') {

    try {
        def version = sh (script: 'chromedriver --version', returnStdout: true).trim()

        if (version) {
            sh "....." 
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        echo "chromedriver: not find"
    }

  }

}
```